# coredata values not contain in my ipa file ios

Tags: ios, core-data, ipa

I had used core-data successfully in my project. But when I build the ipa to test on device, it contains no values stored in core-data. can anyone help me in this context? Thank you in advance

Comment: Similar question and answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043505/can-i-create-a-core-data-object-graph-in-one-application-then-use-it-in-another/15044032#15044032

Answer (score 0):

Whatever objects you had created/saved was stored in the local store in your mac when testing using simulator. So when you start testing on the device the local store gets created from scratch. You need to write code to pre-populate your store.

Another way is to move the sqlite file from simulator to device. Check out
[Core data migration from simulator to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877107/core-data-migration-from-simulator-to-device) for more information.

Comment: Similar question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043505/can-i-create-a-core-data-object-graph-in-one-application-then-use-it-in-another/15044032#15044032

Comment: @radesix: yup. but the OP wasn't aware why it was happening.

Comment: now i done it thank you by calling methods in didfinishlaunch app delegate

Comment: great. If you find this as the solution, accept as answer if you don't mind.